# STM32H7 LTDC LCD MIPI DBI type B

Tags: stm32, lcd, stm32h7

I am using STM32H723ZG with LCD controller ILI9488 working with MIPI DBI type B interface (16 data lines).

Interface pins on the LCD controller are:

- **CS**(Chip Select), **DC**(Data/Command), **RD**(Read signal), **WR** (Write signal).

ST LTDC peripheral does not have DC, RD.

1. Can LTDC CLK be configured to act as WR?
2. How can I control the number of bytes being sent via LTDC (how to control the number of clocks in the CLK signal)?
3. Can I send Commands to the LCD controller (ILI9488) using ST LTDC? If yes, how can I sync between the DC (GPIO) and WR (LTDC?)?